# Reading from a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have data of the following format in "file.txt":

```
b0,  2,1
b1,  3,4
b2,  5,6
b3,  7,8
b4,  9,10
L0, 11, 12
L1, 13, -154
L2, 16, 18
L3,-19,-20
L4,-21,-22
L5,-23,24
L6, 25,28
L7, 27,30
L8, 31,35
L9,-38,40
b0,  0.1,89
```

This data keeps on continuing in the same sequence (i.e., b1,b2,b3...) till a large number. I want to read each of the two numbers of b0...b4 (i.e., those separated by commas in each row) in a matrix format so I can do further calculations with them. Basically each b0 occurs every 15 lines in the "file.txt" and so on for b1,b2,b3,b4. I tried using some sample codes with "textscan" but unfortunately I received errors. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would do a find-replace to delete all whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.). I think this is a delimiter problem.

Comment: How many total lines in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, and read each column with the appropriate conversion specifier.

```
fileID = fopen('scan1.txt');
C = textscan(fileID, '%s %s %f32 %d8 %u %f %f %s %f');
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

see it:

[Documentation Center](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply...but I needed every 15 lines of the data to be stored. can you help with that? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach. It sucks to use a for loop in MATLAB, but I find whenever I work with cells I get caught using them. There's probably a nicer way to do this, but this appears to work for the data you gave me.

```
f = fopen('data.txt');
a = textscan(f, '%s', 'Delimiter', ',');
names  = [];
vals_a = [];
vals_b = [];
for i = 1:3:numel(a{1})
    names  = [names;  a{1}{i+0}];
    vals_a = [vals_a; str2num(a{1}{i+1})];
    vals_b = [vals_b; str2num(a{1}{i+2})];
end
fclose(f);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...but I need vals_a, vals_b for b0 in one matrix and the same for b1 b2 b3 b4 in other 4 matricies. Each value of b0 occurs every 15 lines in the file.txt and same for the other four - b1 b2 b3 b4. Can you please suggest something for this? Many thanks!

Comment: Once you import the data, you can extract the parts you want without too much difficulty, something like: `b2_avals = vals_a[strcmp(cellstr(names), 'b2')];`

Comment: or even, if you want to use your every-15 constraint, `vals_a[1:15:end]`

Comment: hi...the vals_a that's being produced just contains the first 5 values...and I needed a matrix of values (two of them) of b0 that occurs every 15 lines...i hope this makes sense...thanks

Comment: @user2468702 The point is that this approach should read all of the values in the text file into those three matrices (names, vals_a, and vals_b). If you need them rearranged into different matrices, it's very easy to do that. But that's not really what this question is about. With this method, all of the numbers should be correctly parsed and available in MATLAB. If you'd like to ask another question about how to pull the data out of these matrices and arrange them in some other way, feel free to do so as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have comma-separated values you need to change the delimiter used by `textscan`. To combine the two numbers into an array you could use the `CollectOutput` option:

```
fid = fopen('sample.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f', 'Delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(fid);
```

To extract all `b0` fields:

```
values = C{2}(strcmp(C{1}, 'b0'), :);
```

and to extract the values of all lines beginning with `b0, ..., b4`

```
values = C{2}(ismember(C{1}, {'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'}), :);
```

Comment: hi..this is producing an empty 0x2 matrix for values..i believe

Comment: @user2468702 strange, I pasted your sample data into a file and it works just fine. Does the data in any way differ from the file you are trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

As well as [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) you can use [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) (however [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) might be faster):

```
content = importdata('Samp.txt');
```

then `content.rowheaders` would contain labels (which are repeated of course). And `content.data` encapsulates all the numbers:

```
Data = content.data;
```

Then using [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) you can do the trick:

```
Grouped = mat2cell(Data, ones(size(Data,1),1));
```

This way you will combine data for each label in a cell. Then using:

```
Mat = reshape(Grouped, [15 size(Data,1)/15]);
```

`Mat` would be a cell array containing the whole data in a sorted manner. `Mat{1,:}` is `b0` data for its all occurrences (or use `Mat(1,:)` to get the cell array of all `b0` data).

Hope it helps.